# How to view multiple USB partitions on "Startup Disk Creator"?

Tags: partitioning, startup-disk-creator

Startup Disk Creator does not display multiple partitions on my flash drive. It only shows it as /dev/sdg. I had to use UNetbootin which shows both /dev/sdg1 and /dev/sdg2 as desired. Why is that so? Is it possible to fix this on Startup Disk Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Startup Disk Creator no longer supports multiple partitions, it now creates a single ISO9660 read only partition on the flash drive.

It also no longer supports persistence.

UNetbootin still supports multiple partitions and persistent casper-rw and/or home-rw files with maximum 4GB persistence each.

Mkusb will make a persistent install with ISO9660 OS partition, casper-rw persistence partition, (limited only by drive size), and a NTFS data partition that can be used by Windows and Linux.